# Display an Entire Book Index as a Menu

Tags: nodes

I would like to show an entire book outline as a menu.  Something like this:

```
Topic 1
  Subtopic
  Suptopic
    Sub Subtopic
Topic 2
  ...
```

I have installed the [Menu Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block) module but it seems that I can only ever get it to display one level at a time.  Am I using it incorrectly?  Or is this the way it is designed?  I am using the Bootstrap theme.  Could this affect how many levels are displayed?

I have read about using Views.  Should I just try to create and display a custom view?

EDIT: I have found the perfect example of what I am trying to achieve on the Drupal site itself, https://www.drupal.org/documentation/theme.  On the right hand side is a menu with the heading 'Theming Guide'.  This is the menu that I want to achieve.  I suspect that it does not use the Menu Block module....

EDIT 2: Ok, so I just changed the theme and I got the book navigation that I was looking for, out of the box.  So obviously it's the Bootstrap theme that is suppressing the extra levels of book navigation.  Not sure why...

Comment: Do you have the Menu Block configuration (within the specific block) as displaying the "expanded" menu? This is configured under "Advanced" on the block interface.

Comment: Hi Alex, if you mean "Expand all children of this tree", then yes, I have that checked.

Comment: How about this ? https://www.drupal.org/project/book_menus